# proguard + maven + android Error: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called

Tags: android, maven, proguard

I'm getting an error saying something like below while running proguard through maven. What I dont understand is that it works with ANT without any problem. in additional maven can output 2 files called seeds.txt and usage.txt before get actually crashed, then it failures because of some reason which is I didn't know.

I searched for the error ("Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called") on the internet and tried to apply advices but nothing did solve the problem. Is there someone could give any advice to me? I'm really stucked at this point.

```
utjars, 'D:\Projects\MavenInHerd\Android\SOP\trunk\target\proguard-obfuscated.ja
r', -dump, 'D:\Projects\MavenInHerd\Android\SOP\trunk\target\proguard\dump.txt',
 -printseeds, 'D:\Projects\MavenInHerd\Android\SOP\trunk\target\proguard\seeds.t
xt', -printusage, 'D:\Projects\MavenInHerd\Android\SOP\trunk\target\proguard\usa
ge.txt', -printmapping, 'D:\Projects\MavenInHerd\Android\SOP\trunk\target\progua
rd\mapping.txt']
[INFO] Note: there were 185 duplicate class definitions.
[INFO]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[INFO] Error: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerg
er] if ever called
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. Before start to explain how did I solve the problem I'm going to mention how it was working with ANT without problem but wasn't through maven. It was running with ANT because ANT was looking for project.properties file and its configuration was like below

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Above, my proguard.txt was merging with base proguard-android.txt. Eventually ant was looking for just 1 content.

**but maven did not know anything about project.properties which was the problem.** The solution was merging these 2 files (my proguard-project.txt and ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt) manually.